# TLS 1.2 being used regardless of .net code using TLS 1.1

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm trying to confirm that my application is connecting to SQL server using TLS 1.2.  I am able to see that it's connecting using 1.2 using Wire Shark, but I want to confirm that when I switch back to 1.1 it shows 1.1. However, when I switch to 1.1 in my code, it still shows TLS 1.2 in Wireshark.  Why is TLS 1.2 being used regardless? I'm afraid that it's always showing TLS 1.2 just for the handshake, but it's not actually connecting with TLS 1.2.  It's also not showing server hello in the Windows Network Analyzer, like I read in other Stack Overflow posts.  It is only showing the Client hello.  Is the server hello necessary? Since it's using TDS, I'm not sure if the server hello is supposed to be there.

//when I use this code, it shows as using tls 1.2 in Wire Shark

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

Comment: I solved this by disabling TLS 1.2 in the registry and Wireshark started showing that it uses TLS 1.1. So it seems that changing c# code to use TLS 1.1 doesn't actually force it to use 1.1 but seems to make it the minimum requirement. When I forced Windows to disable 1.2 then the Wireshark reflected the TLS 1.1. If anyone has this problem just know that the C# option does not force lower TLS versions when specified. It's not that I am not happy with Windows choosing a better protocol spec but rather that I wanted to make sure it was using TLS 1.2 for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing C# TLS versions manually to lower number sets the minimum requirement. You will be nudged up to whatever the highest version you have set up on the client machine that is making the connection. For example, if you have TLS 1.2 then setting TLS 1.1 on the C# client will not necessarily use 1.1 but rather 1.2.